# How to load luxon timezone features into mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, momentjs, luxon

I'd like to use the 
    luxon.js 
daylight savings and time zone features in the shell script I use in the mongodb shell.  It's the

```
DateTime.isInDST()
```

function I am after  - Failing this I'd settle for

```
moment.js
```

and an equivalent implementation.

The Runtime Environment is 
Mongo 3.6 running in a docker container on linux VM VirtualBOX
Scripts submitted from the command line (from inside a cygwin csh)

I have pulled a local copy of

```
https://moment.github.io/luxon/global-filled/luxon.js
```

which (I thought) is supposed to have all the dependencies included.

This info is accessed by the script via a
    load(); 
statement

However I get an error

```
TypeError: "_cache.has is not a function"
```

Looking at the source file I see the offending line here - line 2008.

```
if (typeof _cache !== "undefined") {
   if (_cache.has(Class)) return _cache.get(Class);
      _cache.set(Class, Wrapper);
    }
   ....
}
```

the variable _cache is declared a few lines earlier here - line 1998.

```
function _wrapNativeSuper(Class) {
  var _cache = typeof Map === "function" ? new Map() : undefined;
  ...
}
```

My guess is that "Map" is previously defined.  So I hacked the code to be

```
var _cache = undefined;  //I read somewhere that it doesn't need to be pre-defined
....
```

I also checked all my code and could find nothing defined as "Map" - so I don't think there is a local name collision.

At this point I seem to be limping along. 
I can create instances and access the function

```
DateTime.local();  and 
DateTime.toString();
```

and get correct UTC values.

Note, however,instead of being able to use "DateTime" as a global variable (as is documented) I found I had to use

```
luxon.DateTime
```

(as "luxon" is the variable declared in the source)

however when I code

```
var now = luxon.DateTime.local();
var now_tz = now.setZone( "America/Los_Angeles" ); 

trace("time after tz:"+ now_tz.toString()+" reason:" +now_tz.invalidReason+ " explanation:"+now_tz.invalidExplanation);
trace("zone support is:"+luxon.Info.features().zones);
```

I get

```
time after tz:Invalid DateTime reason:unsupported zone explanation:the zone "America/Los_Angeles" is not supported
zone support is:false
```

Which kind of suggests the Mongodb shell has no zone support (unless the earlier hacks somehow invalidated that zone support).

My question:  How do I add the zone support.  And why isn't the instantiation via 
    luxon.js 
working as documented.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- For your Map problem, see here for someone with the same symptoms: https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/459. Pretty sure you (or perhaps Mongo) must have `Map` defined somewhere. And that thing doesn't have `has` defined.
- Luxon's global build exports `luxon`, so the `luxon.DateTime` is expected. See, e.g. here: https://moment.github.io/luxon/
- The environment has to provide the time zone support through the Intl API. See Luxon's docs on that: https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/zones.html#iana-support. If Mongo's shell doesn't have Intl or a new enough version of Intl, then you'll need to polyfill that with https://github.com/yahoo/date-time-format-timezone

Comment: The new [MongoDB Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/) supports `Map` and `Intl`, so it may also work with `Luxon`. As of today the new shell is still in beta phase but in near future this should change.